# Restricting Textbox input to only operator symbols

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a TextBox in my WinForms application and I have a method that I want to use to check that the user passes  `+, -, *, /`.

I'm using the TextBox, so the user can input an operator similar to a calculator.  I know that by default TextBoxes only accept strings and how to convert them but I'm not sure how to check to make sure the input matches the restriction that you want.
I just want to make sure they enter one of these symbols: `+, -, *, /`.

I don't have any code besides my TextBox in my Form and my method with nothing inside because I'm not sure how to start.
Does anyone have suggestions what I can search on Microsoft's website to read more about this or where I can watch videos about restrictions applied to a TextBox? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Every time the text changes, process it to find the first permitted symbol only:

```
//attach this handler code to the TextChanged event
private void OperatorTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){

  //if there is nothing in the box return so we don't crash
  if(OperatorTextBox.Text.Length < 1)
    return;

  //could define this elsewhere
  string permittedCharacters = "+-*/";

  //if the box already contains only one permitted char, return. this stops an endless loop
  if(OperatorTextBox.Text.Length == 1 && permittedCharacters.Contains(OperatorTextBox.Text))
    return;

  //find the first permitted char
  int index = OperatorTextBox.Text.IndexOfAny(permittedCharacters.ToCharArray());

  //and set the box contents to the permitted char. This will cause the textchanged event to raise again. Looping is prevented by the above two checks
  if(index > -1)
    OperatorTextBox.Text = OperatorTextBox.Text[index].ToString();
  else
    OperatorTextBox.Clear();

}
```

Satish's answer will work if the user is pressing keys, but not if they paste. Using the textchanged we can react to any mtheod of altering the text in the box, even pasting a large document in. In that case of paste this method will find the first occurrence of a permitted character and reduce the text in the box to just that character, or clear it if it's all bad input

To put this code in the text changed event handler, double click your textbox on the form designer

Comment: I agree with you, Up voting your answer :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Key Press event, as shown below.

First subscribe to textbox's key press event.

```
 textBox1.KeyPress += TextBox1_KeyPress;
```

In Key press Event code

```
 if(e.KeyChar == '+' || e.KeyChar == '-'|| e.KeyChar == '*' || e.KeyChar == '/' || e.KeyChar == '\b' ) // \b is to handle back space.
        {

        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by subscribe to the textbox's key press event, can you please explain it?

Comment: it is event subscription, So when user type's any text in textbox, you need to get notifiy, that is possible by key press event. In order to get notify you need to subscribe it . A common example is of Button_Click event. So if you want your button click by user to be notified you need to subscribe it. Let me know if you got it